# Button is not wrapping its content

Tags: android, button, layout

I am using a simple horizontal LinearLayout to put 3 buttons next to each other, all the same width. I achieve this by the following xml text:

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:baselineAligned="false" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/help"
                style="android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/help" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close"
                style="android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/closemultigame" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ok"
                style="android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/restartmultigame" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Now the layout looks like this:
[image: screenshot from designer]

The button layout_height is defined as wrap_content, but the rightmost button doesn't wrap its content. It looks different on different devices, on some it looks good.
What I would actually like to achieve is three buttons, same width and same height, each with its text centered both horizontally and vertically. What approach would you propose?

ADDED: the whole layout as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/matchandfit"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/multigameover"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/multigameresult"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/masterresult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/masterresultinfo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:baselineAligned="false" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/help1"
                style="android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/help" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close1"
                style="android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/closemultigame" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ok1"
                style="android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/restartmultigame" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

As Wasim Ahmed pointed out, it is due to the ScrollView. Now I use the ScrollView to make sure that the buttons stay accessible even in landscape on small devices. (The layout is for a Dialog). Is there an other way to always keep the buttons accessible/visible?

WORKAROUND:
The solution or better workaround I found was adding a TextView to the end of the enclosing LinearLayout. This TextView is vertically clipped at about half of its height, But it contains no text, so nobody will notice. Adding some padding to the bottom of the enclosing LinearLayout didn't help

Comment: I just Tried your code and its working fine here..there is no issue with your code..i think your LInearLayout is within another Layout..so it is bound to its height..

Comment: yes, you are right, but the outer linear layout also has a wrap_content for it's height.

Comment: can you post the whole layout Xml?? :)

Comment: yes, appended the whole layout in my post

Comment: dear i ckecked it...its just because of scrollview.

Comment: So, it is not possible to use a scrollview? I am using scrollview because on small devices in landscape orientation the buttons may get unaccessible, because the dialog becomes too tall and there remains no space for the buttons.

Answer (score 8):

Time and again I've observed that the `Button` class **does not** adjust to the text size even if you specify `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

You can do one of two things:

**1.** You can manually set either the text size or the width of your `Button` until the text fits in properly (simulating the appearance of `wrap_content`).

**2.** Use a `TextView` instead (which does wrap the text correctly when you specify `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`)  and you set an `onClickListener` on the `TextView` to simulate the behaviour of a button.

Comment: Same problem with TextView. As Wasim Ahmed pointed out, it is due to the surrounding ScrollView...

Answer (score 7):

Button has `minHeight` by default. Remove `minHeight` of `Button` like so:

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not wrap the height of the button instead use the `fill_parent` to make the buttons's height identical with each other.

**sample:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help"
        style="android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hilfe" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        style="android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="beenden" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        style="android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="neue Pundo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**result:**

[image]

Comment: Copied your xml text, but still same effect on my system (Android 4.2. layout renderer in eclipse, but same result on my Google nexus 7)

Comment: @Gerhard but is it majority of devices??

Comment: It is 50% of my devices :)

Comment: @Gerhard change fill to match parent and update me with the result

Comment: fill parent and match parent is the same, isn't it? Both evaluate to "-1"

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and it worked:

1) Define in ../res/values/strings.xml:

Line1Line1\nLine2Line2

2) Refer it in the layout file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_multilines"
    android:text="@string/multilines"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was not having luck wrapping text within a toggle button using android:layout_width="wrap_content", etc, so I added backslash n (\n) to the label string where I wanted wraps.
For example,
"Press to START"
became,
"Press \nto \nSTART"
This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try using android:layout_width="wrap_content" instead of android:layout_width="0dp" and see id

Comment: layout_width="wrap_content" makes the buttons have different widths

Comment: Then try setting adjusting android:layout_height manually to make all the buttons have same height and no text is cut off!!

Comment: If I set layout_height manually, it works, but what about different devices?

Comment: widht must be match_Parent..in this case

Comment: Try adjusting the font size using sp instead of dp. This should change according to the device.