# MaterialButtons in MaterialButtonToggleGroup can't do wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-togglebutton

I have the following xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_two_state"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/filterA"
            style="@style/customToggleButtonStyle"
            app:cornerRadius="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="läkdsvksd"
            android:textSelectHandleLeft="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:ellipsize="none"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/filterB"
            style="@style/customToggleButtonStyle"
            app:cornerRadius="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:textSelectHandleRight="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:text="öskdjnvksjnbvsnfjknvlsnd fvlnsdkjnvsdklövölkjvndfökljnvljkdfnlvjknlvjkn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

which provides me with two buttons with equal height working as a toggle.

[image]

The problem is that I can't get the same result with MaterialButtonToggleGroup forcing the buttons to one line no matter adding the maxLine, line or minLine tags.

The reason to use MaterialButtonToggleGroup is cleaner code when handling the changes and also getting rounded corner.

Is there a fix for it or should I use a different kind of view?

Comment: Can you please share a rough diagram of what you want?

Comment: Added an image for the toggle button I got from the LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get what I expected.
There are two bugs in this problem:

1. [Button is not wrapping its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200190/button-is-not-wrapping-its-content)
2. [MaterialButtonToggleGroup overrides the maxLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792884/android-adding-a-button-with-multiline-text-inside-materialbuttontogglegroup-doe)

So the fix I have for LinearLayout can be used for MaterialButtonToggleGroup as follows:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggle_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:selectionRequired="true"
        app:singleSelection="true"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/filterA"
            style="@style/customToggleButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="State A" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/filterB"
            style="@style/customToggleButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="State B" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

And add the following lines into my code:

```
binding.filterA.maxLines = 2
binding.filterB.maxLines = 2
```

And now it looks like this:

[image]